# How do I change my package name after already obtaining a Google Maps API key?

Tags: android, package, apk, google-play, google-maps-android-api-2

I was trying to upload my APK on the Market for beta testing and realised that my package name started with com.example which isn't allowed. My app is ready to beta, everything is in place but my package name is not allowed. I've tried changing my package name in Android Tools but my problem is with Google Maps since my app is already signed up with com.example. I can get my app running but Google Maps fails to load.

How do I change my package name after I've signed up with a Google Maps API key?

Comment: Just create another key using the right package name this time, and change it in the xml.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the package name in google api console. Remember, the project name should be the same.

Comment: Who accept it. Question is HOW to do it. And the Answer is JUST do it.

Comment: This answer does not help at all

Comment: Please understand the question the first & then try to answer properly.