# Google Maps API - Renamed Package

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio

Good day, I just would like to ask if it is still possible to rename the package name that is registered in Google Developers  Console? I already have obtained an API key - for enabling G-Maps.

But the problem is, the package name is lacking. 
For example, I registered in Google Console Developers Site:

**com.myapplication.practice.project**

But in my Android Studio my package name is
**com.myapplication.practice.project.app**

How to change the package name in google api console? I have come with this link [change package name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15650798/how-do-i-change-my-package-name-after-already-obtaining-a-google-maps-api-key). I did not find any options to rename the package.

Comment: https://console.developers.google.com/home/dashboard , select proper project in top right menu, click Enable and manage APIs, click Credential in left menu, here's the list of all keys associated with android apps.

Comment: Create a new API key using the new package name

Comment: @EugenPechanec - Thanks, a lot, but I use the "Add package name and fingerprint" button to add your app’s package name. I already did those things. I spent an hour, and I think I cannot rename it the package name that lack .app at the end, so I decided to create new and leave the other. I believed this is not the wise option though.

Comment: @FebiMathew - Thanks, I really did that. When I post this one, I somehow decided to create a new one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to Google Developer Console and Login with your credentials.

Choose "API Manager" --> Credentials --> Choose your Project in the API Keys

Edit the Package Name and Click "Save" Button.